# Read/Write efficiency

Tags: java, performance, scala, io, profiling

I have a SCALA(+ JAVA) code which reads and writes at a certain rate. Profiling tells me how much time each method in the code has taken to execute. How do I measure if my program is reaching its maximum efficiency ? To make my code optimized so that it is reading at the maximum speed that is possible with the give configuration.I know this is hard-ware specific and varies from machine to machine. If there is a short-way to measure the process. If my program is reading and writing at the fastest rate possible by the hardware. (I'm using FileWriter along with BufferWriter.)

Comment: Which operating system do you use? (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, ...)

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a description given your best possible choice might be experimenting. What you could measure:

- Changing the buffer size (this didn't help me when I tried this)
- Switching to NIO (might help for large files)
- Caching the data you read (might help for small files), caching dir content if there are many files in it. Opening a file speed degrades when number of files in a folder grows.

One possible technique to make sure there is no problem with the code with your code profiling is to get the CPU time distribution tree for your method and to expand execution paths taking most of the time. If  all these paths head to Java standard libraries, you're probably reaching your best performance.

**UPDATE**

Some other things & techniques from the hrof you provided.

- With a profiler or some other tecnhinique (I prefer stopwatches as they give more stable and realistic results) you need to find what's your bottleneck.
- Most of the IO can be optimized to use a single buffer - this is less painful with Guava or Apache Commons IO.
- However, there is not much you can do if you're using Jackson in your serialization chain if it's your bottleneck. Changing an algorithm?
- There are slow guys (compared to native filesystem IO) - i.e. `Formatter`s, `String.format` is very slow, Jackson, etc.
- There are typical slow operations with IO - i.e. buffer allocations, string concatenation, too many allocated `char[]` buffers is a smell for IO optimization.

Comment: Nice, What exactly do you mean by Caching the directory data ? Any examples on the approach. Here is a sample splitdown of my memory. http://pastebin.com/PEH8yR3v

Comment: Unfortunately, the criterion you give in the end doesn't really work... even if OP finds that 95% of the time is spent waiting for I/O, he may still be far away from optimum performance...

Comment: Reading small file into memory, if this increases the speed. Could you show us your code, from the hrof dump I see that you are using Jackson, Formatters and regular expressions, any of which might become a bottleneck. In this case optimizing IO makes very little sense. You could also use JDK's JVisualVM which has decent UI for profiling. If you do, please attach a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, in fact, I would be glad to share it with you guys to get it reviewed. http://pastebin.com/q2g8kf2U . This is my code block.